# fill a Local #temptable in SQL with multiple Table variables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 and I would like to Set Multiple OrderIDs to run them through this query. I heard that I would have to use a TempTable but I'm stuck at how to set Multiple Table variables.
This is the original query I use:

```
DECLARE @OrderID int
DECLARE @Status int

-- FF nummer
SET @OrderID = 134
-- Huidige status
SET @Status = 4

BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE FF_Task
SET              tsk_FK_CurrentStatus = NULL
WHERE     (tsk_FK_Order = @OrderID)

UPDATE    FF_Order
SET              ord_FK_CurrentOrderStatus  = NULL
WHERE     (ord_PK = @OrderID)

DELETE FROM FF_StatusLog
WHERE     (stl_PK IN
     (SELECT     TOP (1) FF_StatusLog_1.stl_PK
     FROM          FF_StatusLog AS FF_StatusLog_1 INNER JOIN
     FF_Task ON FF_StatusLog_1.stl_FK_Task = FF_Task.tsk_PK
     WHERE      (FF_Task.tsk_FK_Order = @OrderID)
     ORDER BY FF_StatusLog_1.stl_PK DESC))

DELETE
FROM         FF_OrderStatusLog
WHERE     (osl_Status = @Status) AND (osl_FK_Order = @OrderID)                            

UPDATE FF_Task
SET
tsk_FK_CurrentStatus = (SELECT     TOP (1) FF_StatusLog_1.stl_PK
                        FROM          FF_StatusLog AS FF_StatusLog_1 INNER JOIN
                        FF_Task ON FF_StatusLog_1.stl_FK_Task = FF_Task.tsk_PK
                        WHERE      (FF_Task.tsk_FK_Order = @OrderID)
                        ORDER BY FF_StatusLog_1.stl_PK DESC)
                        WHERE     (tsk_FK_Order = @OrderID)

UPDATE    FF_Order
SET              ord_FK_CurrentOrderStatus  = (SELECT TOP 1 osl_Status FROM
                FF_OrderStatusLog WHERE (osl_FK_Order = @OrderID) ORDER BY osl_CreationDateTime DESC)
WHERE     (ord_PK = @OrderID)
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Thank you.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  That will determine whether we can use a table of orderIDs as a parameter or if we need to turn your parameter into a CSV list of orderIDs.  Or, if this isn't to be a stored proc and is instead a one-off query, then please say so and we can leave out the stored proc ceremony :)

Comment: MS SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Comment: It's a one-off query (but used multiple times over the course of a year)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use table variable or temp table

Also in SQLServer2008+ you can passing [table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to SPs and UDFs.A table-value parameter allows you to pass rows of data to your SPs and UDFs in tabular format. To create a table-valued parameter you must first create a table type that defines your table structure.

```
DECLARE @TableOfParemeters TABLE(OrderID int, Status int)
INSERT @TableOfParemeters
VALUES(134, 4),
      (135, 5)

BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE FF_Task
SET tsk_FK_CurrentStatus = NULL
WHERE tsk_FK_Order IN (SELECT OrderID FROM @TableOfParemeters)

UPDATE FF_Order
SET ord_FK_CurrentOrderStatus  = NULL
WHERE ord_PK IN (SELECT OrderID FROM @TableOfParemeters)

;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY stl_PK ORDER BY stl_PK DESC) AS rn
  FROM FF_StatusLog stl INNER JOIN FF_Task ff ON stl.stl_FK_Task = ff.tsk_PK
  WHERE ff.tsk_FK_Order IN (SELECT OrderID FROM @TableOfParemeters)
  )
  DELETE cte
  WHERE rn = 1  

DELETE
FROM FF_OrderStatusLog
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM @TableOfParemeters t
              WHERE osl_Status = t.Status AND osl_FK_Order = t.OrderID
              )

;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT stl.stl_PK, ff.tsk_FK_CurrentStatus,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY stl_PK ORDER BY stl_PK DESC) AS rn
  FROM FF_StatusLog stl INNER JOIN FF_Task ff ON stl.stl_FK_Task = ff.tsk_PK
  WHERE ff.tsk_FK_Order IN (SELECT OrderID FROM @TableOfParemeters)
  )
  UPDATE cte
  SET tsk_FK_CurrentStatus = stl_PK
  WHERE rn = 1

;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT o.ord_FK_CurrentOrderStatus, l.osl_Status,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY osl_Status ORDER BY osl_CreationDateTime DESC) AS rn
  FROM FF_Order o INNER JOIN FF_OrderStatusLog l ON o.ord_PK = l.osl_FK_Order
  WHERE l.osl_FK_Order IN (SELECT OrderID FROM @TableOfParemeters)
  )
  UPDATE cte
  SET tsk_FK_CurrentStatus = osl_Status
  WHERE rn = 1 

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```